# google-maps-react this.props.google does not exist in type

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, spfx

I am trying to follow the example from
https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react#readme
and I got this error

```
Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<IGoogleMapProps>'.
```

The imports

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from "./GoogleMap.module.scss";
import { IGoogleMapProps } from "./IGoogleMapProps";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class GoogleMap extends React.Component<
  IGoogleMapProps,
  {}
  > {
```

The render method

```
 <Map
style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
google={this.props.google}
centerAroundCurrentLocation={true}
zoom={20}
/>
```

Webpart.ts

```
  public render(): void {
    this.properties.list = this.properties.dropdownProperty;
    const element: React.ReactElement<IGoogleMapProps> = React.createElement(
      GoogleMap,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context: this.context,
        spHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        API_KEY: this.properties.API_KEY,
        lat: this.properties.lat,
        lng: this.properties.lng,
        list: this.properties.list,
        dropdownProperty: this.properties.dropdownProperty,
        google: any //  'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
      }
    );
```

May I know what is the parameter google takes?
Where is it defined?
is there a workaround to make this data?

Comment: What have you defined in IGoogleMapProps interface of props. The error clearly says "google" is not there as a prop. Please check that interface.

Comment: nothing, because I don;t know what to define and the document didn't defined it.

Comment: Then don't pass prop interface and then try.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot I have other API calls via the SharePoint network

Comment: try adding prop "google" with type in any in interface.

Comment: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. in Webpart.ts 
i need to assign a value to google

Comment: public render(): void {
    this.properties.list = this.properties.dropdownProperty;
    const element: React.ReactElement<IGoogleMapProps> = React.createElement(
      GoogleMap,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context: this.context,
        spHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        API_KEY: this.properties.API_KEY,
        lat: this.properties.lat,
        lng: this.properties.lng,
        list: this.properties.list,
        dropdownProperty: this.properties.dropdownProperty,
        google: any
      }
    );

Comment: Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?